# Update a sql table field one time with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Below is my small code for inserting some info into AthleteID. It doesn't actually insert the information to the table though, any help is appreciated. (sorry for asking twice, but I think my first question isn't addressing whatever issue is holding me up here!)

```
<?php

require_once('resources/connection.php');

echo 'hello noob' . '<br />';

$query = mysql_query('SELECT LName, MyWebSiteUserID FROM tuser WHERE MyWebSiteUserID = MyWebSiteUserID');

$athleteId = strtoupper(substr($row["LName"], 0, 2)) . $row["MyWebSiteUserID"];

$update = "UPDATE `tuser` SET `AthleteID`='$athleteId' WHERE `MyWebSiteUserID` = `MyWebSiteUserID`;";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 mysql_query( $update);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to begin..

1) Your using mysql and not mysqli. mysql is now deprecated but you could be on a PHP 4 system so keep that in mind.

2) You are building the $athleteID before you have found out what LName and SkillshowUserID is.

3) Your using a where of 1 = 1. You dont need this as it will return true for every row.

4) So...

```
// Execute a query
$results = mysql_query('SELECT LName, MyWebsiteID FROM tuser WHERE SkillshowUserID = SkillshowUserID');

// Loop through the result set
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    // Generate the athleteId
    $athleteId = strtoupper(substr($row["LName"], 0, 2)) . $row["MyWebsiteID"];

    // Generate an sql update statement
    $update = "UPDATE `tuser` SET `AthleteID`='" . $athleteId . "' " . 
        " WHERE LName = '" . $row['LName'] . "' " . 
        " AND MyWebsiteID = '" . $row['MyWebsiteID'] . "';";

    // Fire off that bad boy
    mysql_query($update);
}
```

Comment: I had to edit this about 8 times to cover everything. Anyone spot anything else let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer/s! I did get it worked out like this...
/**
 * code to populate the AthleteID field, runs in browser
 */

require_once('resources/connection.php');



echo 'Health Check' . '<br />';

$query = mysql_query('SELECT LName, MyWebSiteUserID FROM tuser');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $athleteId = strtoupper(substr($row["LName"], 0, 2)) . $row["MyWebSiteUserID"];
    $update = "UPDATE `tuser` SET `AthleteID`='$athleteId' WHERE `MyWebSiteUserID` = '" . $row['MyWebSiteUserID'] . "'";
    mysql_query( $update);
}